# How to find Palettes in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

How do I get to a Palette that's not in my "Palettes" menu? For instance, I occasionally need "Notation" palette, and it's not in that menu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm running Mathematica 8 on Mac OS X.

From the main menu select `Palettes | Install Palette ...`  In the dialog box choose `Source` then `From File...`.  I found the Notation palette in `/Applications/Mathematica.app/AddOns/Packages/Notation/LocalPalettes/English/`.  Once you've done this the `NotationPalette` should be installed on the menu for future use.